# Modern consumer unit, old wiring. What's left that could go wrong?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wiring

An elderly relative of mine had her fuse box professionally replaced with a new consumer unit that conforms to the 18th addition IET wiring regs. This work was done about 2-3 years ago. Nothing tripped or failed since then, but during last summer some very old 1920s lead-sheathed wiring was spotted and replaced. (about 100 meters of wiring, an old star-network section and some of the lighting circuit)

My relative has lived in the house for about 60 years, By some miracle the lead wiring was still good enough *not* to trip out the modern RCBOs (residual current circuit breaker with overcurrent protection). These combine both RCD (residual current device) and MCB (Miniature circuit breaker) functionality.

This got me thinking, assuming that the RCBOs are working fine, and considering the wiring only (ignoring any appliances that might be plugged in). Are there any plausible faults that could go undetected by the RCBO? If the live and neutral wires short then this should trip the MCB, any leakage between live and earth (or neutral and earth) should trip the RCD, and if either live or neutral break completely then no current will flow and no harm done.

The only plausible fault I could think of would be a partial short between live and neutral that would allow enough current to flow to generate heat to start a fire, but not enough current to trip out the MCB - but doing this without tripping the RCD seems implausible.

What else might have gone wrong ? (and not tripped anything)

(For the curious - the  wiring was in remarkably good condition except for where the lead sheathing had been stripped back at junction boxes. Here, the rubber or gutta-percha was exposed to air and had become cracked and brittle)